# Regarding running multiple functions using millis

Tags: millis

I have been writing code for measuring when the digital signal comes and goes (ON and OFF respectively). I have done the part calculating a single system's downtime (difference in timings between ON and OFF from the system), but when I'm not able to scale up to multiple systems when I try to copy the same code which worked above. So it would be helpful if anyone could provide some insight into how it can be done plus explaining with the code would help.

My code:

```
unsigned long a=0, b=0, difference;  
void setup()   
{    
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  pinMode(2, INPUT);  
  Serial.print("start");  
  Serial.print(",");  
  Serial.print("stop");  
  Serial.print(",");  
  Serial.print("minutes");  
  Serial.print(",");  
  Serial.println("seconds");  
}

void loop()   
{  
 //delay(1000);  
 int A = digitalRead(2);  
 if(A == LOW)  
 {  
  b = millis();  
 }  
 if(A == HIGH)  
  {  
     a = millis();  
     display_output();  
   }  
 delay(3000);  
}  
void display_output()  
{  
 int minutes, seconds, sec;  
 difference = a - b;  
 seconds = int(difference/1000);  
 if(seconds >= 60)  
 {  
  //sec = seconds;  
  seconds = seconds%60;  
  minutes = minutes+1;  
 }  
 //minutes = int(seconds/60);  
 Serial.print((a/1000)+1);  
 Serial.print(",");  
 Serial.print((b/1000)+1);  
 Serial.print(",");  
// Serial.print(difference);  
 //Serial.print(",");  
 Serial.print(minutes);  
 Serial.print(",");  
 Serial.println(seconds);  
 //Serial.println(",");  
}
```

Comment: The question is not very clear.  Are you trying to measure the time between two events in time?  What do you mean by "scale up to multiple systems"?  Interrupts are another way to measure the change of logic state in a signal

Comment: Yeah, I'm measuring the time difference between the time when a signal comes to the Arduino from my machine and when the signal stops. I have multiple machines working simultaneously at different stages and I have to do a project on how often and how long the machines are down. I programmed for one machine and it was working normally, but when i try to program for two or more machines ( note that two machines may go down with some error at same time), i get some random value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should notice there is a problem with your logic:

```c++
 int A = digitalRead(2);
 if(A == LOW)  
 {  
  b = millis();  
 }
```

Here you are testing the state of the pin. If it's `LOW` you take a
record of the time. This is wrong. What you want to record is the time
at which the inputs **falls**, not when it's `LOW`.
This is called [state change detection](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StateChangeDetection). In order to implement
it, you have to compare the pin state that you just read with
*the previous state*. The correct condition is “if the pin was `HIGH`
last time I read it and is now `LOW`”:

```c++
// Global variable:
int pin_state = HIGH;

// Within loop():
int new_pin_state = digitalRead(2);
if (pin_state == HIGH && new_pin_state == LOW) {  // it just fell
    time_of_fall = millis();
    pin_state = new_pin_state;
}
```

Note that this assumes that the default state is `HIGH`. If the pin
turns out to be `LOW` at power-up, then the code will assume it just
fell when the program started.

Next, you have to remove any occurrence of `delay()` from your code.
That will only make your timings wrong. At this point you have
non-blocking code that can easily be adapted to handle multiple input
channels.

Then you have to identify the variables that are channel-specific, and
have a per-channel version of each variable (arrays are useful here).
Then your code only needs to loop through the arrays.

Instead of having multiples arrays, you can make the code cleaner by
grouping all the channel-specific data into a single data structure:

```c++
struct Channel {
    byte pin;
    byte state;
    unsigned long fell, rose;  // times of fall and rise
};
```

This way you can have a single array that holds all the data for all the
channels:

```c++
const int CHANNEL_COUNT = 5;

Channel channels[CHANNEL_COUNT] = {
    { 2, HIGH, 0, 0 },
    { 3, HIGH, 0, 0 },
    { 4, HIGH, 0, 0 },
    { 5, HIGH, 0, 0 },
    { 6, HIGH, 0, 0 }
};
```

The code now becomes quite simple: you just loop through the array and
handle one channel at a time:

```c++
void setup()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CHANNEL_COUNT; ++i) {
        pinMode(channels[i].pin, INPUT);
    }
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("pin,fell,rose,low time");
}

void loop()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CHANNEL_COUNT; ++i) {
        Channel &c = channels[i];
        byte new_state = digitalRead(c.pin);
        if (c.state == HIGH && new_state == LOW) {  // input fell
            c.fell = millis();
        }
        else if (c.state == LOW && new_state == HIGH) {  // input rose
            c.rose = millis();
            display_channel(c);
        }
        c.state = new_state;
    }
}
```

The function `display_channel()` is left as an exercise to the reader
;-) (hint: it's prototype should be
`void display_channel(const Channel &c);` in order to avoid
unnecessarily copying the data structure.

Next step in code modularity would be to turn the `Channel` structure
into a class with a proper constructor, and make `display_channel()` a
method of that class.

Comment: What about a link to the state-change-detection example? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StateChangeDetection

Comment: This code looks neat and will definitely try with this one. I don't know much about constructors and structure things. Will learn about that. I used a delay in my program so as not to have too many data points and instead the data once in two or three seconds will be enough plus its not a time critical application, so I don't know if using millis function is overkill for my application. Thank you though :)

Comment: @Jot: Good idea. I added the link.

Comment: @RajeshAnand10: 1. Learning about object-oriented programming (classes with constructors and methods) is useful, but you can live without it for simple projects like this. 2. `delay()` was useful in your previous version _only_ because you got the logic wrong. Once you properly detect state changes, it serves no useful purpose. 3. What do you mean by “overkill”? Do you believe `millis()` is more heavyweight than `delay()`? It's not. For your particular problem, it's the right tool for the job.